# Codeigniter error inserting array in db

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I am currently making a registration form where you could register by batch but i am getting an error 
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'test@gmail.com' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `user` (date_registered, `test@gmail`.`com`) VALUES (NOW(), '')
my code is
controller

```
public function registerbatch(){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('surname','firstname','age','school','course','email')); $i++) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("surname[$i]", "surname[$i]", "required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname[$i]", "firstname[$i]", "required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("age[$i]", "Age[$i]", "required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("school[$i]", "School[$i]", "required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("course[$i]", "Course[$i]", "required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("email[$i]", "Email[$i]", "required");
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {



      $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('surname');
        $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('name');
         $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('age');
         $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('school');
        $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('course');
         $reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post('email');
          foreach  ($reg_dat_multi as $reg_dat) {
           $this->user_model->add_batchuser($reg_dat);
        }






         $this->load->view('user/home_view');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('user/batch_register');
        }

    }
```

for view

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>  
    <form class="form" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'user/registerbatch'; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">


        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++): ?>
        <br>
        Surname: <input type="text" name="surname[]">
        <br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="firstname[]">
        <br>
        Age:<input type ="int" name ="age[]">
        <br>
        School: <input type="text" readonly value="<?= $school ?>" name="school[]">
        <br>
        Course:<input type ="text" name ="course[]">
        <br>
        Email:<input type ="text" name ="email[]">
        <br>
        <br>


    <?php endfor ?>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>


</body>
</html>
```

and model

```
public function add_batchuser($reg_dat) {
        $this->db->set('date_registered', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('user', $reg_dat);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `insert_batch` of codeigniter?

Example in the [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My     name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

for your Use Case assuming you had the same number of surname, firstname, and all of the inputs you can foreach to create an array then add use the `insert_batch`:

```
public function add_batchuser($reg_dat) {

    foreach ($reg_dat[firstname] as $key => $value) {
        $details[$key]['firstname'] = $reg_dat['firstname'][$key];
        $details[$key]['surname'] = $reg_dat['surname'][$key];
        $details[$key]['age'] = $reg_dat['age'][$key];
        $details[$key]['course'] = $reg_dat['course'][$key];
        $details[$key]['email'] = $reg_dat['email'][$key];
        $details[$key]['date_registered'] => $this->database_now_time();
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('user', $details);
}
```

please remove the:

```
foreach  ($reg_dat_multi as $reg_dat) {
    $this->user_model->add_batchuser($reg_dat);
}
```

you can just use:

```
$reg_dat_multi = $this->input->post(null, true); //This will get all the data in post parameters
$this->user_model->add_batchuser($reg_dat_multi);
```

Comment: the number of array i would be inserting would be based on the value given by the user example if the user had an input of 3 it will create 3 forms that should be inserted in the db. would that still be aplicable?

Comment: got a little problem with it but it works now thanks !